# MongoDB - Group and sum aggregation in a map structure

Tags: spring, mongodb, sum, aggregate

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and I need to group the sum of the total of all invoices for each unique date in all the documents in a collection. This is a summary of the collection, where data is stored in a key-value pair:

```
Document 1:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "key": "invoice-date",
      "value": {
        "$date": "2023-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "invoice-total",
      "value": 110.29
    }
  ]
}

Document 2:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "key": "invoice-date",
      "value": {
        "$date": "2023-05-04T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "invoice-total",
      "value": 47.18
    }
  ]
}

Document 3:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "key": "invoice-date",
      "value": {
        "$date": "2023-05-05T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "key": "invoice-total",
      "value": 22.05
    }
  ]
}
```

This should be grouped into a map and the result should be as follows:

```
"2023-05-04T00:00:00.000Z": 157.47
"2023-05-05T00:00:00.000Z": 22.05
```

This what I have tried thus far in Spring 3.1.4:

```
        MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("data.key").in("invoice-date", "invoice-total"));

        
        GroupOperation groupStage = Aggregation.group("invoice-date")
                        .sum(ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("data.key").is("invoice-total")).then("data.value")
                                        .otherwise(0))
                        .as("total");


        ProjectionOperation projectionStage = Aggregation.project()
                        .andExpression("_id").as("invoice-date")
                        .andInclude("total");


        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                        matchStage,
                        groupStage,
                        projectionStage);

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "documents", Map.class);
```

However, the returned total is always 0 and the date is null. How can I make the aggregation work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not working as you are trying to group by "invoice-date" which is a value but not a field.

It can be solved by extracting the value from the `data` array as the `invoiceDate` and `invoiceTotal` fields (second stage).

For converting the set of dates with respective total, you need to `$group` all documents into one document and convert into key-value pair.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "data.key": {
        $in: [
          "invoice-date",
          "invoice-total"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      invoiceDate: {
        $getField: {
          input: {
            $first: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$data",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.key",
                    "invoice-date"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          field: "value"
        }
      },
      invoiceTotal: {
        $getField: {
          input: {
            $first: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$data",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.key",
                    "invoice-total"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          field: "value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$invoiceDate",
      total: {
        $sum: "$invoiceTotal"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      data: {
        $push: {
          k: {
            $toString: "$_id"
          },
          v: "$total"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5cGGE5_KtvX)

*Sorry that I am not a Spring/Java MongoDB Developer*, based on what I researched, the Spring code should be as:

```
MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("data.key").in("invoice-date", "invoice-total"));

AggregationOperation setStage = new AggregationOperation() {
    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new Document("$set", 
            new Document("invoiceDate", 
                new Document("$getField", 
                    new Document("input", 
                        new Document("$first", 
                            new Document("$filter", 
                                new Document("input", "$data")
                                    .append("cond", 
    new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$$this.key", "invoice-date"))))))
                                    .append("field", "value")))
                .append("invoiceTotal", 
                    new Document("$getField", 
                        new Document("input", 
                            new Document("$first", 
                                new Document("$filter", 
                                    new Document("input", "$data")
                                        .append("cond", 
                                            new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$$this.key", "invoice-total"))))))
                        .append("field", "value"))));
    }
};

GroupOperation groupStage = Aggregation.group("invoiceDate")
    .sum("invoiceTotal")
    .as("total");

AggregationOperation secondGroupStage = new AggregationOperation() {
    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new Document("$group", 
            new Document("_id",  new BsonNull())
                .append("data", 
                    new Document("$push", 
                        new Document("k", 
                            new Document("$toString", "$_id"))
                .append("v", "$total"))));
    }
};

AggregationOperation replaceRootStage = new AggregationOperation() {
    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return new Document("$replaceRoot", 
            new Document("newRoot", 
                new Document("$arrayToObject", "$data")));
    }
};

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    matchStage,
    setStage,
    groupStage,
    secondGroupStage,
    replaceRootStage);

return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "documents", Map.class);
```

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59703984/8017690. And you can use [MongoDB Compass to export the query to specific language](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/agg-pipeline-builder/export-pipeline-to-language/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$getField` I would use `$arrayToObject`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $match: { "data.key": { $in: ["invoice-date", "invoice-total"] } } },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $arrayToObject: {
               $map: {
                  input: "$data",
                  in: { k: "$$this.key", v: "$$this.value" }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: { $toString: "$data.invoice-date" },
         total: { $sum: "$data.invoice-total" }
      }
   },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         data: { $push: { k: "$_id", v: "$total" } }
      }
   },
   { $replaceWith: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ps2LdCTKPBV)